# Data management for buses and and employees

Tags: c

I am relatively new so any help would in improving this and future codes. The code involves basic file management for two different files, one for buses and another for the employees and I am not very experienced with file managing so expect some beginner errors and mistakes

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SIZE 100

int provbid;
int proveid;
int login();
void menu2();
void menu3();
void bus_mgm();
void emp_mgm();


typedef struct bus_data
{
    int busid;
    float distrav;

}bus;

typedef struct emp_data
{
   int empid;
   float hrswrkd;
}emp;

void addb(int*,bus[]);
void adde(int*,emp[]);

void viewb(int*,bus[]);
void viewe(int*,emp[]);
void updateb(int*,bus[]);
void updatee(int*,emp[]);
void deleteb(int*,bus[]); 
void deletee(int*,emp[]);
int searchb(int,bus[]);
int searche(int,emp[]); 
void readfileb(int*,bus[]);
void readfile(int*,emp[]);
void writefileb(int,bus[]);
void writefilee(int,emp[]);

int main(){







    int option1;
    int p = 0;
    p = login();
    if (p==1){
    printf("\n-*-*-*-*-*     Welcome to 'Company Manager' user      *-*-*-*-*\n");
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\nPlease slect an option:\n");
    printf("1 Bus managment menu\n");
    printf("2 Employee managment menu\n");
    printf("3 Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &option1);

    while (option1 != 3){

        switch(option1){
            case 1:
                menu2();
                break;
            case 2:
                menu3();
                break;
            default:
                {
                    if (option1 != 3){
                        printf("\nOption is not supported.");
                    }
                }
        system("pause");
        printf("Please slect an option:\n");
        printf("1 Bus managment menu\n");
        printf("2 Employee managment menu\n");
        printf("3 Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &option1);

        }
    system("pause");
    }

    return 0;
}

int login(){
int pwd = 12345678;
    int count = 0;
    int pw;
    printf("Welcome to 'comapnay manager' login screen\n");
    while (count != 5){
        printf("Please enter password. \n");
        scanf("%d",&pw);
        if (pw == pwd){
            printf("Password accepted");
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n Wrong Password, try again.\n");

        }
        count++;
        printf("You have done %d chances out of 5\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}



void menu2(){
    int choice;
    int bl = 0;
    bus bslist[SIZE];
    readfileb(&bl, bslist);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    printf("Welcome to the bus menu.\n\n");
    printf("Please select an option:\n\n1: Add bus information\n2: View bus information\n3: Update bus information\n4: Delete bus information\n5: Return to login menu\n6: to exit the prgram\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    while (choice != 6){

        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                addb(&bl, bslist);
                break;
            case 2:
                viewb(&bl, bslist);
                break;
            case 3: 
                updateb(&bl, bslist);
                break;
            case 4:
                deleteb(&bl, bslist);
                break;
            case 5:
                main();
                break;  
            default:
                if (choice != 6){
                    printf("you have not selected a proper option\n");
                }
                else{
                    goto end;
                }

        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        printf("Please select an option:\n\n1: Add bus information\n2: View bus information\n3: Update bus information\n4: Delete bus information\n5: Return to login menu\n6: Exit\n ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }
    end:
        exit(0);
}

void menu3(){
    int choice;
    int el = 0;
    emp eplist[SIZE];
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    printf("Welcome to the Employee menu menu.\n\n");
    printf("Please select an option:\n\n1: Add Employee information\n2: View Employee information\n3: Update Employee information\n4: Delete Employee information\n5: Return to login menu\n6: Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    while (choice != 6){

        switch (choice){
            case 1:
                adde(&el, eplist);
                break;
            case 2:
                viewe(&el, eplist);
                break;
            case 3: 
                updatee(&el, eplist);
                break;
            case 4:
                deletee(&el, eplist);
                break;
            case 5:
                main();
                break;
                default:
                if (choice != 6){
                    printf("you have not selected a proper option\n");
                }
                else{
                    goto end;
                }
            }
        system("pause");
        printf("Please select an option:\n1: Add Employee information\n2: View Employee information\n3: Update Employee information\n4: Delete Employee information\n5: Return to login menu\n6: Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        }
        end:
            exit(0);
}

void addb(int *loc ,bus list[]){
    printf("Add bus information");

    int n =  searchb( *loc, list);

    if (n != -1){
        printf("This ID is already being used.");
    }
    else
    {
        list[*loc].busid = provbid;

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Please enter the total distance traveled, the number you have given will be accepted as km: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[*loc].distrav);

        *loc = *loc + 1;
    }
}

void adde(int*loc ,emp list[]){
    printf("Add Employee information\n");

    int n =  searche( *loc, list);

    if (n != -1){
        printf("This ID is already being used.");
    }
    else
    {
        list[*loc].empid = proveid;

        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Please enter the total hours worked: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[*loc].hrswrkd);

        *loc = *loc + 1;
    }   
}


void viewb(int *loc ,bus list[]){

    int meh;

    printf("Showing information of all buses.\n");

    for(meh = 0; meh < *loc; meh++)
    {
        printf("Bus ID is: %d\n", list[meh].busid);
        printf("Distance traveled is: %.1f km\n", list[meh].distrav);
    }
}

void viewe(int *loc,emp list[]){
    int meh;

    printf("Showing information of all Employess.\n");

    for(meh = 0; meh < *loc; meh++)
    {
        printf("Employee ID is: %d\n", list[meh].empid);
        printf("Hours worked are: %.1f hours\n", list[meh].hrswrkd);
    }
}


void updateb(int *loc,bus list[]){
    int tempbid;

    printf("Update bus information");

    tempbid = searchb(*loc, list);

    if( tempbid== -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter new distanced traveled: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[tempbid].distrav);

        printf("Distance traveled has been updated. \a");
    }
}

void updatee(int *loc ,emp list[]){
    int tempeid;

    printf("Update employee information");

    tempeid = searche(*loc, list);

    if( tempeid== -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter new hours worked: ");
        scanf("%f", &list[tempeid].hrswrkd);

        printf("Hours worked has been updated. \a");
    }
}


void deleteb(int *loc, bus list[]){
    int tempbid, meh;

    printf("Delete bus info");

    tempbid = searchb(*loc, list);

    if(tempbid == -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(meh = tempbid; meh < *loc; meh++)
        {
            list[meh].busid = list[meh + 1].busid;
            list[meh].distrav = list[meh + 1].distrav;
        }

        *loc = *loc - 1;
        printf("Bus ID %d has been deleted.\n", tempbid);
    }
}

void deletee(int *loc,emp list[]){
    int tempeid, meh;

    printf("Delete employee info");

    tempeid = searche(*loc, list);

    if(tempeid == -1)
    {
        printf("This ID does not exist.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(meh = tempeid; meh < *loc; meh++)
        {
            list[meh].empid = list[meh + 1].empid;
            list[meh].hrswrkd = list[meh + 1].hrswrkd;
        }

        *loc = *loc - 1;
        printf("Employee ID %d has been deleted.\n", tempeid);
    }
}


int searchb(int loc, bus list[]){
    int meh;

    printf("Enter bus ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &provbid);

    for(meh=0; meh<loc; meh++){
        if(list[meh].busid == provbid)
        return meh;
    }
    return -1;
}

int searche(int loc ,emp list[]){
    int meh;

    printf("Enter employee ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &proveid);

    for(meh=0; meh<loc; meh++){
        if(list[meh].empid == proveid)
        return meh;
    }
    return -1;
} 


void readfileb(int *loc, bus list[]){
    FILE *bd;

    bd = fopen("Bus Data.txt", "r");
    if(bd != NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(bd))
        {
            fscanf(bd, "%d %f ", &list[*loc].busid, &list[*loc].distrav);
            *loc = *loc + 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(bd);
}

void readfile(int *loc, emp list[]){
    FILE *ed;

    ed = fopen("Employee Data.txt", "r");
    if(loc != NULL)
    {
        while(!feof(ed))
        {
            fscanf(ed, "%d %f ", &list[*loc].empid, &list[*loc].hrswrkd);
            *loc = *loc + 1;
        }
    }
    fclose(ed);
}
```

Comment: The title has been changed to better follow the code review guideline at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking.

Comment: _expect some problems_ is unfortunately not specific enough for us. Does the code work as it should?

Comment: (To determine whether or not code works as specified, a *specification* would be invaluable.)

Answer (score 2):

the posted code is ignoring the returned values from `scanf()` `fscanf()`, and `system()`

Critical success/fail information is contained in those returned values, so the code should be checking those returned values

Please read [why while(!feof(ed)) is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

suggest replacing:

```
while(!feof(ed))
    {
        fscanf(ed, "%d %f ", &list[*loc].empid, &list[*loc].hrswrkd);
```

with:

```
while( fscanf(ed, "%d %f ", &list[*loc].empid, &list[*loc].hrswrkd) == 2 ) {
```

Much better to use the returned value from `fscanf()` to control the loop

regarding:

```
ed = fopen("Employee Data.txt", "r");
if(loc != NULL)
```

What about when the call to `fopen()` fails?

in function: `menu2()`  the call to `readfile()` should contain a parameter that indicates the max number of 'slots' that can be filled, so the array of `structs bus bslist[SIZE];` is not overflowed.

regarding:

```
else{
                goto end;
```

a `goto` is (almost) always a bad idea.  Suggest fixing the code logic so no `goto` is needed

Please do not use  for indenting as everyone's editor can be set for different tab widths.  Strongly suggest using 4 spaces where there are current  characters

regarding:

```
system("pause");
system("cls");
```

the shell commands: `pause` and `cls` are not portable. so if you want this code to run on anything but Windows, please use more generic methods

regarding:

```
case 5:
            main();
            break;
```

DO NOT call the function: `main()`  rather use some kind of looping construct

regarding:

```
end:
        exit(0);
```

do you really want to exit the whole program?

regarding:

```
fflush(stdin);
```

The function: `fflush()` is for output streams, not input streams.  The C standard specifically states using `fflush()` on a input stream is undefined behavior.  Some compilers, like `visual c` allow it, but such deviations from the C standard should not be used.  Suggest:

```
int ch;
while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n' ){;}
```

regarding:

```
 printf("Welcome to the Employee menu menu.\n\n");
 printf("Please select an option:\n\n1: Add Employee information\n2: View Employee information\n3: Update Employee information\n4: Delete Employee information\n5: Return to login menu\n6: Exit\n");
```

it is best to honor the right margin, amongst other reasons, so the code can easily be printed.

Suggest:

```
printf("Welcome to the Employee menu.\n\n");
printf("Please select an option:\n\n"
    "1: Add Employee information\n"
    "2: View Employee information\n"
    "3: Update Employee information\n"
    "4: Delete Employee information\n"
    "5: Return to login menu\n"
    "6: Exit\n");
```

which makes it much more readable and does honor the right margin

For ease of readability and understanding:

1. follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
2. separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` ``` do...while``switch ``` `case` `default` via a single blank line.
3. separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)